# How do I find all files of a specific type in RHEL on the command line?

Tags: redhat, find

I am looking for files of type `.flv`, `.avi`, etc

I would like to see a list of all the files (on my server) of those file types (I don't mind doing it one by one, i.e. seeing all the files of `.flv`, then all the files of `.avi`).

Then, once I identify the ones I want to move, how do I copy several files that are scattered all over the filesystem to a specific folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to search for files on GNU/Linux systems. The two main ways are `locate` and `find`:

- `locate` uses a database of files known in the whole system to find documents. It is very useful but requires to keep this database up-to-date (with `updatedb`), which can take a long time;
- `find` searches for files in a given directory. It is usually slower than `locate` (it has no persistent database) but is more fine-tuned.

So, if you need to find all files on your system that match your criteria, you can use `locate`:

```
$ locate --regex "avi|flv" | grep '\.\(avi\|flv\)$'
```

whereas if you're searching in a specific directory and want to make sure to have no cache delay effect, you can use `find`:

```
$ find /path/to/your/directory -regex '.*\.\(avi\|flv\)'
```

Now, to copy these files to a specific folder:

```
$ locate --regex "avi|flv" | grep '\.\(avi\|flv\)$' | xargs cp /path/to/specific/folder
```

or

```
$ find /path/to/your/directory -regex '.*\.\(avi\|flv\)' -exec cp {} /path/to/specific/folder \;
```

Comment: I am now running `updatedb` and the cursor is just blinking. How can I know when it is done ? Should I open a new terminal window and do something else ? The last time I tried a large operation, the cursor just stayed blinking forever - until I quit it after about 6 hours, by that time I was pretty certain it had finished. There another way I can know ?

Comment: One of the fondamentals of Unix commands is that they don't output anything unless necessary, so it is normal for a command to stay blinking while it's working, unless it's running in verbose mode. You can use the `--verbose` flag to `udpatedb` if you want to see all it's doing, but beware that it will make the process even longer, since printing of all files will limit the processing speed.

Comment: Ahh...thanks....I don't mind that, at least I will know when it's done than when it's not.

Comment: Is there any flag that I can pass that can tell me how much has been completed? In a %, for instance ?

Comment: @marc: Not that I know of. What you can do is combine `--verbose` with a pipe to `pv` to see the throughput bandwidth (how fast it's being processed): `updatedb --verbose | pv`

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Raphnik's comment, you can save yourself a pipe through grep by puting into the regex part of locate or find commands: `'\.avi$|\.flv$'` -- it will match files with .avi and .flv extensions.

Comment: Ah thanks. I had tried something like `\.(avi|flv)$` without success ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Probably more elegant ways to do this with find -exec or xargs but here's a quick hack:

```
updatedb
```

then

```
for fred in `locate *.flv | awk ' { print $1 } '` do;
mv "$fred" /my/dest/folder/
done
```

(etc)

Comment: Forgive the silly question, but is all of that code ? as in...`for fred` ? That seems a bit strange to me, but I am a complete Linux n00b, so I could be misunderstanding. Or am I supposed to substitute something else for `fred` ?

Comment: `locate` only outputs file names, so I don't see the point in the `awk` pipe. Also, `for` cuts on spaces, so files with spaces will fail with that loop. Also, this could all be done with `xargs` instead of a loop, especially since `mv` can take more than 2 arguments without a problem. Then, the question was not to *move* the files but to *copy* them. Using this command will result in losing the original files. Finally, locate doesn't match on *whole* filenames unless you specifiy it, so `*.flv` is not a best match.

Comment: @marc.gayle: `for fred in ...` defines a loop with variable `fred`, which is then used as `$fred` inside the loop.

Comment: yep $fred = arbitrary variable name for use in for loops...